# uiautomator - button is not getting selected

Tags: android, travis-ci, android-uiautomator

I have the following piece of code in my test:

```
    device.findObject(By.text("Widgets")).click();
    device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.text("Widgets").selected(true)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
    device.waitForIdle(LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
    assertTrue("Widgets button is selected after the click",
               device.findObject(By.text("Widgets")).isSelected());
```

Where "Widgets" is the component of TabWidget. This works when I run it on emulator on my computer, but assertion fails when the test is performed on Travis. Here's the link to the failed build: https://travis-ci.org/aragaer/jtt_android/builds/239115606

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it is the problem that I have already encountered two years ago - [Disabling first-run greeter on fresh android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824832/disabling-first-run-greeter-on-fresh-android-emulator)

The combination of [uiautomator](/questions/tagged/uiautomator) and [travis-ci](/questions/tagged/travis-ci) hinted me that it was something I've encountered earlier.